# Importing Python package with custom settings

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, plugins

I'm working on a simple dictionary tool, with a base class that can be extended by plugins to represent different dictionaries. The plugins are organized in the filesystem like this:

> ```
> plugins/
> ├── dict1
> │   ├── ...
> │   ├── settings.py
> │   └── dict1.py
> └── dict2
>     ├── ...
>     ├── settings.py
>     └── dict2.py
> ```

The main application discovers and loads the plugins like this:

```
import os

PLUGINS_DIR = 'plugins'
PLUGINS_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), PLUGINS_DIR)


def discover_dictionaries():
    for plugin_name in os.listdir(PLUGINS_PATH):
        plugin_path = os.path.join(PLUGINS_PATH, plugin_name, plugin_name + '.py')
        if os.path.isfile(plugin_path):
            name = '.'.join([PLUGINS_DIR, plugin_name, plugin_name])
            module = __import__(name, fromlist=['Dictionary'])
            yield plugin_name, getattr(module, 'Dictionary')()
```

As illustrated above in the filesystem layout, most plugins have a `settings.py` file in the same directory, containing custom settings of the plugin. The plugin's main package imports the settings like this:

```
from settings import dictionary_path
```

This works fine in Python 2.7. But in Python 3 I'm getting this stack trace:

```
Error: could not import Dictionary from /tmp/webdict/plugins/wud/wud.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <listcomp>
  File "/tmp/webdict/util.py", line 14, in discover_dictionaries
    module = __import__(name, fromlist=['Dictionary'])
  File "/tmp/webdict/plugins/wud/wud.py", line 4, in <module>
    from settings import dictionary_path
ImportError: No module named 'settings'
```

The `settings.py` file is in `/tmp/webdict/plugins/wud/settings.py`, the program works fine with Python 2 but not with Python 3. Before running with Python 3, I wiped all the `*.pyc` files with:

```
find plugins -name '*.pyc' -delete
```

The complete project is open-source on [GitHub](https://github.com/janosgyerik/webdict).

To reproduce the problem:

```
# clone test1 branch
git clone -b test1 https://github.com/janosgyerik/webdict

# raises ImportError -> what I want to fix
python3.4 -c 'import util; print([x for x in util.discover_dictionaries()])'

# NO ImportError -> GOOD (the IOError doesn't matter for this test)
python2.6 -c 'import util; print([x for x in util.discover_dictionaries()])'
```

In other words, in Python 2 the plugin has no problem with `from settings import blah`, having `settings.py` in its own directory, but this doesn't work in Python 3. How should I do this?

I'm not very happy with the `discover_dictionaries` method either. Probably it can be done better but I don't know how. Please enlighten!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Python 3 you'll need to use a relative import: `from .settings import dictionary_path`.

Otherwise it's looking for `settings` somewhere on your `sys.path`.

For consistency you can get this behavior in Python 2 with `from __future__ import absolute_import`